# Update MySQL database table with data from another database, based on matching field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Using PHP5, I'm needing to access two different databases (on the same server) but with different login credentials. Then get data from one database and update the other database for a record matching a unique field value. Here's what I have so far...

```
$link2->query("UPDATE db2.table2 
    INNER JOIN db1.table1 
        ON db1.table1.email = db2.table3.email 
SET db2.table2.field2 = db1.table1.field1");
```

Where I am totally lost is how to handle the fact that both databases have different connections. Which connection to I query? How do I incorporate the connection of the other database?

Comment: Select from one database, then insert/update in the other. You cant do both at once. (unless you connect through them with the same connection)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use MySQL database from two different server in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469877/how-can-i-use-mysql-database-from-two-different-server-in-php)

Comment: @Len_D, this is not a duplicate. That thread was dealing with two different servers. I have two databases, same server. The desired task there is also different. Thanks though. :)

Comment: @Mr Jack, I now have credentials that give me access to both databases. So... knowing that, any suggestions for moving forward?

Comment: Do the select and put the results in 1 variable, then do an insert with the 2nd connection string.

Answer (score 0):

To use a single query to hit two different databases, two things must be true:

1. Those databases must be on the same MySQL server.
2. The username you use must have appropriate access to both databases, and all tables involved.

If these two conditions don't hold you need to retrieve the information to your program with a connection to one database, and then update the tables in the other database with its connection. That can sometimes be hard.

I believe your best bet in this case is to persuade your database administrator to add privileges to the account you use to modify `db2` so it also has access to read `db1`. (Of course that won't help if they're not on the sane server.)

Comment: So I now have access to both databases with the same credentials. So how would I modify this to filter through a list of records in db1, updating records in db2? Any problems exist is the code I'm starting with?